# return truthy value from Array.some or _.some

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I want to return the truthy value from the array.Some instead of "true",

I'm using

```
var category;
arduair.aqi_ranges[pollutant].some((item,index)=>  {
  var min =item.range[0];
  var max =item.range[1];
  if (_.inRange(c,min,max)){
    category = index;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

But is a very ugly expression.

Comment: use `find` instead of `some`

Answer (score 0):

looks like your input data is object

variant 1. use lodash **pickBy**

```
_.chain(arduair.aqi_ranges[pollutant])
    .pickBy(function(item, cat) {
        return _.inRange(
            c,
            item.range[0],
            item.range[1]
        )
    })
    .keys()
    .first() //remove this step if you want all mathed category
    .value();
```

variant 2. use lodash **reduce** and **find** (more reliable variant)

```
_.chain(arduair.aqi_ranges[pollutant])
    .reduce(function(result, val, key) {
        return _.concat(
            result,
            _.merge(val, {category: key})
        );
     }, [])
     .find(function(item) { // use filter if you want all mathed category
         return _.inRange(
             c,
             item.range[0],
             item.range[1]
         );
      })
     .get('category')
     .value();
```